# is there a way to capture ip addresses of people browsing your website privately?

Tags: ip-address

I don't want to block, but do want to keep track of the activity of users who browse privately.  Is there any way to capture that data?

I think private browsing is becoming more common and just want to see how much volume is being blocked.  Also, there are a few users I'd like to just keep an eye on.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a programming question as outlined in the [help]. And it's called *private* browsing for a reason. :-)

Comment: "how much volume is being blocked" - what? Blocked? I don't think that's what private/incognito mode does. And as a website operator, why do you care whether people are in private mode when they visit your site?

Comment: Private browsing has nothing to do with whether the IP address is visible to the server or not anyway …

Comment: Sorry, Ken.  I guess I'm confused.  I run a website and it feels like somehow, programatically, you could get this information.

CBroe, it doesn't?  So... if I've got my server logs I can find a specific ip address?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly this question does not belong in stackoverflow. While I see you want to write some sort of programming to test this, you have not provided any code to show what you have attempted or done so far.

Secondly, there is no way to block an ip address.
Private browsing only means temporary internet files such as cache, cookies etc are only kept for the duration of the browsers session.

At a packet level, you will still find ip addresses and the rest of the information.

Private browsing is designed just to keep a users details private on the computer he is using from others also using the machine.